# Why is my DataGridView falling apart when it's redrawn?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, datagridview

On startup, my DataGridView with dynamically created rows and columns looks fine.

The DGV is on a TabPage. When I switch to the other TabPage and back again, the DGV goes all to Dallas. It almost looks as if a new rendering of itself is being drawn on top of the old rendering, but a little bit off-centered.

I've got scream shots of both the "good grid" and the "bad grid" at:

http://warbler.posterous.com/good-grid-bad-grid#

Comment: Post some code - hard to say w/out seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wholly cow!

Commenting out this code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
        return cp;
    }
}
```

...solved the problem. That code was necessary when I was using a TableLayoutPanel, but obviously it causes problems when replacing a TLP with a DGV.